# Compute the conditional expectation $E[X|X<\tau]$, where $\tau$ is a constant

Tags: probability

$X$ is a random variable with known distribution function $F(x)$, how do I compute the conditional expectation $E[X|X<\tau]$, where $\tau$ is a constant?

Comment: $$
\mathbb E[X\mid X<\tau] = \frac{\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{X<\tau}]}{\mathbb P(X<\tau)} = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\tau x\ \mathsf dF(x) - \tau\mathbb P(X=\tau)}{F(\tau)-P(X=\tau)}
$$

Comment: @Math1000 $P(X=\tau)=0$ considering $X$ is continuous. Do we need to keep this in the result?

Comment: It was not stated in the problem that $X$ was continuous! But yes, if it is, then remove the $\mathbb P(X=\tau)$ terms.